# return type for overriding operator=

Tags: c++

Let's say there is this code:

```
struct Tester
{
  int value = 0;
  void operator=(const Tester& original)
  {
    value = original.value;
  }
};
```

Purpose of overriding operator= is to use it like normal assignment operator. This function would definitely take parameter's "value" and put it to host object's "value".

However, other programmers suggest to use:

```
Tester& operator=(const Tester& original)
{
  value = original.value;
  return *this;//edited
}
```

with return type of Tester as reference. The first function would do exactly the same. Why and how would that be useful?

Comment: used for assigning the value on one function call. Better Programming Practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The first function would do exactly the same

Not quite. The second version you posted omits a `return` statement. So it has undefined behavior. But once it's fixed:

```
Tester& operator=(const Tester& original)
{
  value = original.value;
  return *this;
}
```

It can be used to chain assignments:

```
a = b = c;
```

Something your `void` version cannot be used for.

Comment: That makes total sense. Thanks!